# Young fit man pursuing a less healthy man through a hive structure

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, dystopia

I'm looking for a short story about a young fit man pursuing a less healthy man through a hive structure. I think he captured or killed him. The young man has superior muscles developed by the hive authority- maybe a god-supercomputer. He seems very complacent in his faith in this all-knowing entity. The hunted man seems to be ranting at him and dents his faith in the system. He investigates the system himself and discovers in the past there was a war between two factions on earth or wherever it is, populationists and anti-populationists. The populationists wanted further human population growth etc. and they won, maybe because they had the numbers. I think the young man finds out he was from a anti-populationists family and he was brainwashed etc.

It is probably from the early 80s or 70s.

Comment: Wow thanks for that, that's spot on

Answer (score 11):

I've read this story, and what's more I've seen a question asking for the same story on this site.  Searching among the answers I'm pretty sure it is the one described here: [Short story about people hibernating in pods, and the system is breaking down](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/68414/short-story-about-people-hibernating-in-pods-and-the-system-is-breaking-down/74151#74151)

Wake Up To Thunder by Dean Koontz, collected in "Children of Infinity"

Unfortunately I do not have a copy of it, and I've not been able to find the text online.  But I am going of my memory of reading it.  But I was able to recognize the story from both your description and from the description in the other question.

- The protagonist wakes up from dreams.
- He has a voice in his mind (some kind of supercomputer) that tells him to hunt down a renegade.
- He is naked - he is expected to attack and kill the renegade with his bare hands.
- He finds him, but the renegade is armed.  The hunter sees no point in dying needlessly, so he waits for other hunters to arrive so they can tear the man apart together.
- Meanwhile the victim tells his story - and shows him some kind of museum (I think there was a mock up of a spaceship).
- Humanity was overpopulated and exploring space for new worlds.  But why they waited they put people to sleep in pods.  Their brains were linked together for computing power.
- There was war between populationists who were okay with this, and the anti-populationists who wanted to control the population.  The populationists won (there were a lot more of them).
- So the population grew rapidly and all the surplus people were left sleeping until they could be taken to another world.
- But the collected brains became independently sentient, took over and now all of humanity sleeps in pods.  No one is exploring the stars.
- The pops are breaking down, but the intelligence has no plan - each time someone wakes up it dispatches hunters to kill him/her.
- Our hunter does not believe a word of it - when fellow hunters turn up they kill the victim.  He returns to his pod.
- But then he wakes up and there is no voice.  He realizes that the victim was telling the truth.  He sets out to try to shut down the computer, before hunters come for him.

Comment: Yeah, reading the question I immediately though of this story too.